# How To Write XML file foreach datarows in dataset?

Tags: c#, vb.net

How can I write xml foreach datarow in dataset? I have dataset with 5 record in table, I want to write to xml file with 5 xml files. In one xml file have one record.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just make a loop ?

```
foreach (Datarow row in dataset.table["Table"].Rows)
{
    WriteXML();
}
```

Maybe you're wondering how to write the XML?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Dim dtXML As New DataTable

Dim dtData As New DataTable

Dim dtRow As DataRow

Dim dtXMLRow As DataRow

Dim XMLFilename As String



'==============Fill dtData from database============

'Add matching columns to your XML datatable

dtXML.Columns.Add("Column Name")

dtXML.Columns.Add("Column Name2")



For Each dtRow In SQLTable.Rows

'Clear last row

dtXML.Rows.Clear()



'Make new row

dtXMLRow = dtXML.NewRow



'Copy data from one Datarow to another

dtXMLRow("Column Name") = dtRow("Column Name").ToString

dtXMLRow("Column Name2") = dtRow("Column Name2").ToString



'Add the new built row to the dtX

dtXML.Rows.Add(dtXMLRow)



'Write XML file

dtXML.WriteXml(XMLFilename)

Next
```

Can do a quick google and find lot of stuff on this.